# Executing PowerShell Script with Parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, datagridview

I'm adapting [this solution](http://hmemcpy.com/2015/04/preventing-a-certain-windows-update-from-installing-on-windows-10/) to a Windows Forms solution. So far I've been able to execute the `Get-WUList` command with no problems. But it doesn't seem to go well with the `Hide-WUUpdate`. This is what I've tried so far:

```cs
public class PowerShellController : IPowerShell
{

    //Created at a global scope so anyone can fetch it.
    InitialSessionState initial;
    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker;
    Runspace runspace;
    PowerShell ps;

    //The View to Control
    IView view;

    //The Helper GridViewProcessor class
    IGridViewProcessor gp;

    //Initializing the Controller - Loads the Module.
    public PowerShellController()
    {
        initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"C:\Users\Jose\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate\PSWindowsUpdate.psd1" });
        scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke();
        scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process");

        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
        runspace.Open();

        using (ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Please Wait. This will take a while to load.");

    }


    public void SetView(IView view, IGridViewProcessor gp)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.gp = gp;
    }


    public void GetAvailableUpdates()
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Ok. The program will kind of hang. This is normal." +
                        "This Means that it will start looking for updates "
            );

        IEnumerable<PSObject> WUList; //Placeholder for the PS Executed Command

        using (ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //Adds the PowerShell Command
            ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-WUList");
            //Executes the PowerShell command
            WUList = ps.Invoke();
        }

        //Loads the Model - Can be later on rewritten for Ninject Support.
        List<WindowsUpdate> model = new List<WindowsUpdate>();
        int id = 1;
        foreach (PSObject result in WUList)
        {
            WindowsUpdate item = new WindowsUpdate
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = result.Members["Title"].Value.ToString(),
                Size = result.Members["Size"].Value.ToString(),
                Type = UpdateType.Undefined,

            };
            model.Add(item);
            id++; //Icnrease ID count
            //Console.WriteLine("Update Name {0} --- Size: {1}", result.Members["Title"].Value.ToString(), result.Members["Size"].Value.ToString());
        }

        //Adds it to the view:
        view.AddUpdateToGrid(model);
    }

    public void HideSelectedUpdates(DataGridView grid)
    {
        //Gets SelectedUpdates to the WindowsUpdate model
        var SelectedUpdates = gp.GetSelectedUpdates(grid);
        using (ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            foreach (var update in SelectedUpdates)
            {
                ps.Commands.Clear();
                ps.Commands.AddCommand("Hide-WUUpdate").AddParameter("Title",update.Name).AddParameter("Confirm", false);

                //ps.Commands.AddCommand("Hide-WUUpdate -Title \""+update.Name+"\"");
               var result = ps.Invoke();

            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Updates Have been hidden");

    }

}
```

The method I can't seem to work is the `HideSelectedUpdates(DataGridView grid)`.

Script gets executed and no exceptions are thrown, but it doesn't seem to reflect any changes at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run the `Hide-WUUpdate` command directly from the console to see if you have it working with the specified parameters?  Just trying to see if the issue is in your program or in your use of this command.

Comment: @KeithHill: Yup. I can run it perfectly from PowerShell. On the PowerShell console it asks me if I want to proceed, that's why I've added the confirm:false parameter. I've also tried it in the console this way and it works!

I really don't know where the problem is :(

Comment: Because the program passes OK. There are no errors registered, but it seems that it does not take effect.

Comment: Did you check `ps.Streams.Error` to see if there is anything in that collection after you invoke that command?

Comment: @KeithHill: I did. No errors shown :(